# Zend framework 2 get baseUrl from console controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2, viewhelper

I tried to find a way to get base url of mixed (http + CLI) application. CLI is used to do some regular notifications, where app url is used.

I tried this, but it returns me only `"http://"`

```
print_r($this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('ServerUrl')->__invoke());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work for console requests. The `serverUrl` is extracted from the http request object ([`Zend\Http\Request`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-http/blob/master/src/Request.php)), since a console request is wrapped in a console request object ([`Zend\Console\Request`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-console/blob/master/src/Request.php)) this information won't be available for such requests.

You can define (hardcode) an url in a global config or a constant and use this instead.

For example add a `host.config.local` file to your `application/config/autoload` folder:

```
<?php

return array(
    'hostname' => 'http://www.example.com'
);
```

Now you can get your hostname from your service manager:

```
$config = $serviceManager->get('config');
$hostName = $config['hostname'];
```

Comment: No, i run this code in the console controller. It returns me "http//"

Comment: @bksi A console request is not an http request. So when you do a console request there is no such thing as a `serverUrl`.

Comment: Indeed. So back to my question: How i can get app url from console controller?

Comment: @bksi There is no such thing as a server url when you do a console request. What url do you expect to get? Can you give an example?

Comment: As i said in my question i have an application that can be accessed by url. I use console to do some notifications by crontab. I need to get the application url, to use it in the generated notification emails.

Comment: As i said in my answer you cannot get the url since a console request doesn't have such thing as a server url in the request object. You can define (hardcode) an url in a global config or a constant and use this instead.